# Winform MouseMove event (left button down) fired when Doubleclick title bar to maximize window

Tags: winforms

I'm trying to write some code to "drag" something in my Winform application. The code looks below:

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.textBox1.AppendText($"{DateTime.Now}\r\n");
        }
    }
```

But when I double click the title bar to maximize the window, the `MouseMove` event is fired and the `e.Button` is `MouseButtons.Left` so I can see some text appears in the text box. However, this does not happen when use the `Maximize window` button (next to the `X` button).

What is going on?

My envrionment:
Windows 10 enterprise,  Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 v16.5.4, .net framework 4.6.1

Comment: Most mouse actions are triggered on the mouse-up event.  The maximize button click for example.  What's a bit quirky about double-clicking the titlebar is that the OS resizes on the 2nd mouse-*down* event instead of the mouse-up event.  You'll get a mouse-move, the window position changed so the relative mouse position changed.  And you see the button down.  Using Control.DoDragDrop() is the best way to avoid surprises.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. but `Control.DoDragDrop()` seems to be used for dragging objects(e.g. files) between different windows event between different applications. It's a little bit 'heavy' for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change condition to check how many clicks was performed:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Clicks == 1) // <-- Here
    {
        this.textBox1.AppendText($"{DateTime.Now}\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but I cannot drag either. The `AppendText` line never run when I drag in the form.

Comment: What you want to drag? `textBox1`? Or `Form1`?

Comment: I draw some my own shapes on the Form and I want to use mouse to drag them.

Comment: And... why you need `Form.MouseMov`e event instead of your `OwnShape.MouseMove` to drag them?

Comment: My shapes are not `Controls` . They are painted by using 'g.FillRect()'. So my objects themselves does not process mouse events.